# Mule Service Proxy Issue

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule

I'mm trying to proxy a service but somehow its not working the way other services did, what am I doing wrong?

This is the original service http://webservicesh.sc.gov.br/SEA/Materiais/Fardamento/WS_Materiais_v1.wsdl

What I did was:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="BiometriaRH"
      inboundAddress="http://LocalIP/services/BiometriaRH/WS_BiometriaRH_v1"
      outboundAddress="http://webservicesh.sc.gov.br/SEA/RecursosHumanos/biometria/WS_BiometriaRH_v1.asmx"
      wsdlFile="BiometriaRH.wsdl"/>
```

It does access the WSDL file but I can't load the service any place like soapUI or Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you configure `wsdlFile="BiometriaRH.wsdl"`? Did you manually customize it?

If not, and assuming a WSDL is served at this URL http://webservicesh.sc.gov.br/SEA/RecursosHumanos/biometria/WS_BiometriaRH_v1.asmx?wsdl , then you only need:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="BiometriaRH"
  inboundAddress="http://LocalIP/services/BiometriaRH/WS_BiometriaRH_v1"
  outboundAddress="http://webservicesh.sc.gov.br/SEA/RecursosHumanos/biometria/WS_BiometriaRH_v1.asmx" />
```

Comment: Well, i did customize it, but i will try your way, so far im unable to access the service using eclipse just if i do it directly...

Comment: its missing part of your message but assuming it was to use wsdlLocation pointing to that URL, it did not work... still proxying the WSDL but not the service itself, cant load inside soapUI or so:/

Comment: Dossot can i ask you to create a proxy server using that url i passed and see if you are able to proxy it and consume the service using soapUI or eclipse?

Comment: I'm not able to reach http://webservicesh.sc.gov.br/SEA/RecursosHumanos/biometria/WS_BiometriaRH_v1.asmx?wsdl : is it behind a firewall or something?

Comment: Crap it probably is :/

Comment: Sorry, yes, reviewed the missing part.

Comment: Yeah my test was that but still not working i will look at the service and see if it is missing something... if im able to pass the fw i will relay a message to you, i think creating a proxy service would be easier to see what is the problem im facing...

Comment: If the remote service exposes its WSDL where the proxy expects it (ie `outboundAddress + ".wsdl"`) then the `web-service-proxy` just works out of the box.

Comment: Ok, solved the issue, the answer you gave and what i did was right :) but the service was wrong, now the it team fixed the service and its all working :)

Comment: Do you mean you need to define the `wsdlFile` attribute? If yes, why?

Comment: Not anymore, was taking some methods from the WSDL file, that was why but now its not needed so left without it :) tyvm!!!